# Expo document picker install IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, expo

Hello I'm trying to install `expo-document-picker` [doc](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/).

I think I did everything right but I still have the error: `[Error: DocumentPicker requires the iCloud entitlement. If you are using ExpoKit, you need to add this capability to your App Id. See 'https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/advanced-expokit-topics#using-documentpicker' for more info.]` only on IOS simulator

Expo SDK: 43.0.0

I'am on the **Managed workflow** case (cause I only have `/ios/settings.json`). So I did this :
[image]

[image]

I ran the command `expo build:ios -c` and the build successfully end:
[image]

I also add this in my `app.json` :

```json
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-document-picker",
        {
          "appleTeamId": "*********"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

The only thing i didn't do was this:

> [...] you'll need to revoke your existing provisioning profile and run `expo build:ios -c` [...]

Does it mean i have the both of my profiles ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to revoke one of provisioning profiles that is used and add the new provisioning profile with the icloud identifier... This will apply the changes needed...

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/#managed-workflow